# In Oracle APEX, How to check number of working hours as a Developer I spent?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have been working in Oracle APEX for quite sometime, I have the administrative tab and other but I want information in number of hours I have worked per day for last 6 months.

I need sql query & logs to show that I was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apex:

```
Administration > Monitor Activity > Application Changes by Day / By Developer / ...
```

or Query:

> SELECT * FROM apex_developer_activity_log

Both may depend on automatic purging though.

And if you've been working for 6 months, then surely you'll have something to show for it.

Comment: I have checked all those, they are not showing number of hours :(
 - By Developer Shows me - Hw many components I works on
 - By Changes show me - components changes & some unknown percentile for each row. I need <b>WORKING HOURS</b>, could that be possible ?

Comment: No, I believe not. The built-in audit mechanism does nothing but log the time of the change and the component changed. Think of it as a usual audit trigger with create by/on+updated by/on but then on the apex tables. If you would want workspace access time you can get those from `APEX_WORKSPACE_ACCESS_LOG`by looking at authenticating to app 4500, but again, that is only time of login, and I'm quite sure this data does get pruned, so 1 year back may be too much. So no, I don't think there is a total of hours to be gathered, only approximates.